# Most queried and highest billable BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to check the most queried BQ tables, the most expensive billable BQ tables and also the highest slot usage and the associated users.

Anyone could provide the simplest way (query) to do this in BiqQuery?

Comment: Take a look in the BigQuery audit logs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs. You can configure a sink to write these logs into a bigquery table and then query it to get the data you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try exploring table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*`. This table contains details on jobs that were executed (query, total_bytes_billed, etc.) see [jobs metadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) documentation for more details per field.

Based on your requirements, you might want to try the query below. Feel free to tweak the query as needed.

```sql
select 
  parent.user_email,
  sum(parent.total_bytes_billed) as sum_total_bytes_billed,
  count(ref.table_id) as query_table_count,
  ref.table_id,
  sum(parent.total_slot_ms) as slot_usage
  
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER as parent, unnest(referenced_tables) as ref
  group by ref.table_id,parent.user_email
  order by sum_total_bytes_billed desc
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: This was tested on my test project, hence a small sample size and there are no other users that query on this project.